# Group on category and summarize property in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I got a schema for products. Each time a user looks at a product I increase the "views" property by one. Now I want to list the most popular category.
How can I group on category an summarize the views on all products in same category?

```
const ProductsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    programId: {
      type: Number,
    },
    
    productName: {
      type: String,
    },
    productPrice: {
      type: Number,
    },
    productCategory: {
      type: String,
    },
    views: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  { collection: 'products' }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly simply `$group` by `$productCategory` and `$sum` the number of views.

```json
yourModel.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$productCategory",
      "views": {
        "$sum": "$views"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "views": -1
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-MLtQ1wYSC0).

Also you can `$limit` to get only the top value: [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CgBUT4033b5)